# Strange paragraph formatting using tcolorbox and wrapfigure

Tags: tcolorbox, paragraphs, wrapfigure

First of all, my apologies for the quite large MWE; I tried to reduce it to the minimum but, given that the problem occurs quite randomly, it is difficult to maintain it.

Given the following MWE, you can see that sometime the paragraph is formatted really in a strange way --- this is just and example, but it occurs randomly that the first line is just the first word of the paragraph. See:

[image]

Is it possible to fix it? Or is just that tcolorbox and wrapfigure don't go well together?

MWE following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1.75cm, bottom=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\colorlet{solcolor}{green!40!black}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{common/.style={
        colback=yellow!10,
        colframe=solcolor!60,
        halign=flush left, leftrule=4mm,
}}
\newtcolorbox{solbox}[1][]{common, breakable,
    coltext=solcolor,
    #1}
\newtcolorbox{circbox}[2][]{common, nobeforeafter,
    colback=white,
    hbox, title = {#2},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\def\isr{i_\mathit{SR}}
\def\vsr{v_\mathit{SR}}
\begin{solbox}[title={Punto 2}]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{circbox}{Circuito de polarización}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (-0.5,1) rectangle ++(4.5,-6);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{circbox}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    El circuito de polarización es el mismo que hemos usado para el apartado anterior;
    en este caso el condensador actúa como un circuito abierto.
    Esto implica que la tensión de polarización de $v_{O2}$ es:
    \begin{equation}
        V_{O2_Q} = 0
    \end{equation}

    Para calcular la corriente y tensión de polarización del dispositivo,
    usamos entonces el mismo procedimiento que en el punto anterior:
    \begin{align}
        V_{SR_Q} &= \text{1 V} \\
        I_{SR_Q} &= \text{1 mA}
    \end{align}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{solbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `halign=flush left`, or use `halign=left instead`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer --- yes, it works. If you add an answer I'll happy to accept it (and if you can explain *why*, the better...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `halign=flush left`. This uses internally `\raggedright` and so allows very short lines. In combination with the parshape setting of wrapfig you get the bad linebreaking (I didn't not try to understand how TeX exactly decides the line breaking, but the problem can be demonstrated with a simple parshape too, see below). Either remove the option completly or replace it by `halign=left` which will use the second setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil \parindent=0pt
\parshape 9
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0pt \textwidth
\lipsum*[1]

\rightskip=0pt plus 2em \parindent=0pt %better
\parshape 9
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
  0pt \textwidth
\lipsum*[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]